# Can't suspend Debian machine: wakes up immediately after sleep ("PM: Device usb1 failed to suspend async")

Tags: debian, usb, suspend, sleep

Since I installed the latest Debian updates yesterday (udev, systemd, ...) I can't put my Debian 9/KDE machine to sleep. It wakes up immediately after suspending (`systemctl suspend`).

/var/log/syslog has the following:

```
..Stopping disk
parport_pc 00:01: disabled
e1000e: EEE TX LPI TIMER: 00000011
dpm_run_callback(): usb_dev_suspend+0x0/0x20 [usbcore] returns -16
PM: Device usb1 failed to suspend async: error -16
PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
parport_pc 00:01: activated
..Starting disk
..
rtc_cmos 00:07: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
```

There were also some other messages at other tries such as a wlan-related "driver in IPS". But no matter what I try I always get the exact same message:

*PM: Device usb1 failed to suspend async: error -16*

**What I tried so far**

- Removing my wlan driver with `sudo rmmod`, `sudo modprobe -r` and `sudo dkms remove`. Couldn't put it to sleep after doing that. Also the module always gets loaded again after rebooting after "successfully" removing it (it's also not shown in `lsmod` anymore). I have reinstalled it with dkms now.
- Disconnecting all USB devices except of my keyboard to suspend the machine and disconnecting all USB devices except of my mouse to suspend the machine and immediately disconnecting the keyboard/mouse after suspending it.

Any other ideas what I should try? I find it strange that it displays that usb error even though all usb devices are disconnected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was an internal card reader which apparently was connected via usb as well.
This seems to be related to: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201997
Did not find out what "usb1" was. `lsusb` still shows the exact same devices as before.

Comment: I similarly found that if I unplug my USB-C hub before suspending, the computer stays suspended.

Comment: @JohnMcGehee Does your USB-C hub perhaps have a network interface? Might work to disable 'wake on lan':  `ethtool -s eno1 wol d`